# Asynchronous queues with serial data for several channels

Tags: go

There was a problem ... I have three structures that implement one interface. I have a function that processes the structure data, but it happens that the processing of the data for some structure can take a few seconds. Data must be processed sequentially.

I did it this way:

```
type dater struct {
    value int
}

type waiter struct {
    data chan *dater
}

func (dat *waiter) conf(wait bool) {
    go func() {
        for {
            obj := <-dat.data
            if wait {
                time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            }
            fmt.Println("WAIT", wait, *obj)
        }
    }()
}

func (dat *waiter) gowrite(w *dater) {
    dat.data <- w
}

func main() {
    waiters := []*waiter{}

    first := &waiter{data: make(chan *dater)}
    first.conf(false)
    waiters = append(waiters, first)

    second := &waiter{data: make(chan *dater)}
    second.conf(true)
    waiters = append(waiters, second)

    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        for _, wait := range waiters {
            wait.gowrite(&dater{value: i})
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
WAIT false {0}
WAIT false {1}
WAIT true {0} (SLEEP 5 sec)
WAIT false {2} (will appear after 5 seconds)
WAIT true {1}
WAIT false {3}
WAIT true {2}
WAIT false {4}
WAIT true {3}
WAIT false {5}
```

I want:

```
WAIT false {0}
WAIT false {1}
WAIT false {2}
WAIT false {3}
WAIT false {4}
WAIT false {5}
WAIT true {0} (5 seconds have passed and we show the first message)
WAIT true {1} (This message will appear after 5 seconds)
WAIT true {2}
WAIT true {3}
```

The "gowrite" function of the "second" structure waits until the channel of the structure "first" receives the data. But it's important for me that they process the data asynchronously without blocking each other. In this case, all channels receive the correct data.

Comment: im not an avid go programmer, but it seems that you are writing anti-pattern code.

Comment: @Rafael it did not help :)

Comment: check out [pipeline](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) models in go. you should almost *never* call sleep in a go routine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need two separate buffered channels, [like so](https://play.golang.org/p/9hVAqT_imY):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    wg.Add(2)
    go first()
    go second()
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        a <- i // send to first
        b <- i // send to second
    }
    close(a)
    close(b)
    wg.Wait()
}

func first() {
    for {
        d, ok := <-a
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        if !ok {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("first job:", d) // do first job here.
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func second() {
    for {
        d, ok := <-b
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        if !ok {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("second job:", d) // do second job here.
    }
    wg.Done()
}

var a = make(chan int, 1000)
var b = make(chan int, 1000)
var wg sync.WaitGroup
```

output:

```
first job: 1
first job: 2
second job: 1
first job: 3
first job: 4
first job: 5
second job: 2
first job: 6
first job: 7
first job: 8
second job: 3
first job: 9
second job: 4
second job: 5
second job: 6
second job: 7
second job: 8
second job: 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I add "sleep" time.Sleep (100 * time.Second) after "fmt.Println (" second job: ", d)" then I get: first job: 1, first job: 3 (?), Second job : 2. I would like to see: first job: 1, first job: 3, second job 2, first job 5, first job 7 etc. Your example has the same problem as mine.

Comment: I need the data in both structures to be the same. In the first there was 1,2,3,4 and in the second 1,2,3,4. With a long second processing, so that the former still receives data, when the second processes a long process, it continues to execute further. First: 1,2,3,4,5. Second: 1,2 (sleep), 3,4,5. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Commented the condition in a loop and it seems to be good. But... I looped up to 100 in the data place in the array, and I again got the lock on the first channel.

Comment: use buffered channel. you need to elaborate, your question is not clear. edit your question  add sample & output.

Comment: Posted by. Look here please.

Comment: The solution works as it should! But without using the indication of the buffer is not how? I can not know how much data will be written. After all, when the 1000 mark is reached, the process will stop again ... How to be in this case? And can I somehow close the channel when I reach a certain amount of data in the buffer?

Comment: so increase your channel buffer size

Comment: I understood, thanks for the help. I read https://blog.golang.org/pipelines and it says that you can use data that can be written / read. Is there still no solution? I used https://gist.github.com/moraes/2141121 to write data, and I read the data in a separate thread. But my processor is very loaded with this solution, but it looks more elegant.

Comment: with data you provided i can't help more,  it seems you need some algorithms for your problem,  for better help here in Stackoverflow, it is better to ask One question per thread as simple as possible. and provide each Question with your sample input and output.